# Looping Pandas Column Names To Create New Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am seeking to loop the columns in a dataframe and when the column name meets a criteria create a new dataframe and/or add it to an existing dataframe. For exmaple - my current dataframe has the following column names:

open
high
low
IVV
volume
open
high
low
EWH
volume
open
high
low
INDY
volume
open
high
low
EWG
volume
open
high
low
ENZL
volume

I want a loop which will find IVV,EWH,INDY,EWG, and ENZL and add them to their own dataframe.

I have tried the following:

```
Indexlist = ['IVV', 'EWH', 'INDY', 'EWG', 'ENZL']
```

Attempt to drop the values columns:

```
for column in data:
    print(column)
    if column != Indexlist:
        data.drop([column], axis=0))
```

Attempt to del the columns

```
for column in data:
    print(column)
    if column != Indexlist:
        del data[column]
```

Attempt to select the columns

```
data_sample = data[column].isin(Indexlist)
```

all these methods are throwing errors.

Comment: How working `data[Indexlist]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think need check substrings of columns names by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex - join all values of list by `|` for `OR`:

```
data1 = data.loc[:, data.columns.str.contains('|'.join(Indexlist))]
```

If need select by columns names use subset:

```
data1 = data[Indexlist]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Index.isin`](http://pandas.Index.isin) with [`pd.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for Boolean indexing:

```
data_sample = data.loc[:, data.columns.isin(Indexlist)]
```

Or direct indexing, if you know in advance that all list elements exist as columns in your dataframe:

```
data_sample = data[Indexlist]
```